# How to achieve this type of animation in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-animation

Take a look at this design I did for an interface of a game I want to develop on Android:
http://www.moboing.com/smallshow.jpg

When a user touches a balloon, I want that star/glare animation to play with the stars dropping down.  All I'm curious about is the best general direction/approach to making that animation possible while developing the app in eclipse/java.

I was thinking making a few variations of stars as transparent PNG's, and making them animate on touch but I'm a newbie so I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the animation like a sequence of images and then use the AnimationDrawable class to make it animated. Let me show you an example:

```
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_animation);
AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();

// We need to add each image to our final animation setting time interval between them
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_1), 200);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_2), 200);
animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_3), 200);

animation.setOneShot(false);

my_image.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);    // Set as background to see it
animation.start();    // Start playing the animation
```

Where:

- `my_animation`: your ImageView into your desire Layout.
- `img_1`, `img_2`, `img_3`: images that compounds your animation (your should
  create and save them into `res/drawable` folder).

I hope it can help you and draw a way to do it by yourself :)

PS: this should be into a method on the activity that you want (for example, into `onCreate` to show it when user start).